# RecyclerView onbindViewHolder

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to set Views in onBindViewHolder But cant choose them

i should use them id in layout or....?

Adapter:

```
public class RV_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
private Context context;
private List<Image> images;

public RV_Adapter(Context context, List<Image> Images){
    this.context = context;

    images = Images;
}



@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rv_layout,parent,false);
    return new ImageViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Image image=images.get(position);
    holder.

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return images.size();
}

class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

   private ImageView rvimg;
   private TextView rvtxt;
   private TextView rvcontent;



public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
       super(itemView);
       rvimg=itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_imgview);
       rvtxt    =itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_title);
       rvcontent=itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_content);
   }
 }
}
```

Any advise how to set holder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this:

```
public class RV_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RV_Adapter.ImageViewHolder> {
...
}
```

Reimplement the abstract methods again.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing a demoadapterclass . Please try to implement it. Let me know if you face any issues.

```
public class DemoAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<DemoAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<Image> mImageItemList;
private Context context;
public IRvGalleryImageListener mIRvGalleryImageListener;

public interface IRvGalleryImageListener {
    void onClickGalleryImage(Image item, int position);
}

public DemoAdapter(Context context, List<Image> itemList) {
    mIRvGalleryImageListener = (IRvGalleryImageListener)context;
    this.mImageItemList = itemList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.galery_image_list_item, null);
    return new ViewHolder(layoutView);
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView mTvTitle;
    ImageView mIvGalleryImage;
    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        try {
            mTvTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_title_main);
            mIvGalleryImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_gallery_image);

            v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mIRvGalleryImageListener.onClickGalleryImage(mImageItemList.get(getAdapterPosition()),getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(mImageItemList.get(position).getTitle()) && !mImageItemList.get(position).getTitle().equals(""))
        holder.mTvTitle.setText(mImageItemList.get(position).getTitle());


         holder.mIvGalleryImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(AppConstants.IMAGE_ENDPOINT_CACHED_IMAGE + mImageItemList.get(position).getImage()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.mImageItemList.size();
}
```

}